# Linux command and eof in one line

Tags: linux, command-line, eof

I want to ask if is possible to combine linux command and <

```
sendmail -S "lalalal" -f "dailaakak" -au "kakakak" <<EOF
>lalal:lalal
>opp:ttt
>ggg:zzz
EOF
```

I want to have something like that `sendmail -S "lalalal" -f "dailaakak" -au "kakakak" <<EOF; lalal:lalal; opp:ttt; ggg:zzz; EOF`

I need to use that not in bash script

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it has to be in one line without newlines use that:

```
echo -e "lalal:lalal\nopp:ttt\nggg:zzz" | sendmail -S "lalalal" -f "dailaakak" -au "kakakak"
```

`echo -n` interpretes escapes characters such as `\n` as a newline.

Comment: @Dainius Sorry your shell doesn't accept that kind of process substitution. I changed my answer, see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking whether you can use the `<< EOF` in an interactive shell then the answer is yes, you can.

Note this functionality is called *here document* and that there can be any word instead of `EOF`. For example:

```
$ cat - << someword
> Here you
> can
> write text with as many
> newlines as you want.
> someword
Here you
can
write text with as many
newlines as you want.
```

(`cat -` prints whatever it receives on stdin)

For more information on here documents you can read for example this: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html

Answer (score 0):

I have tried and succeeded but it's messy. EOF simply does not like to accept substituted new lines for some reason so it needs to be put in another format.  Now I'm sure this could be achieved with an expect script one one line but the below is what I have made and works.

```
echo "ssh localhost `printf "<< EOF\necho "Working!" >> /tmp/myfile \nEOF\n"`" > file.sh; chmod770 file.sh; ./file.sh

printf "<< EOF\necho Test! >> /tmp/myfile \nEOF\n" | xargs ssh localhost
```

Please ensure chmod file permissions are suitable for your own work case! Putting it into an environment variable instead of a file is also likely to work.